# Code not working if i delete the for

Tags: html, xml

i got this code working, it's just an example that i'm making:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","info.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<div>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CAJA1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</div>");
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But i want to delete the for, but when i delete it, screen show nothing!, i tried many ways but still can't make it work

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","info.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
  document.write("<div>");
  document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO").getElementsByTagName("CAJA1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</div>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why it's this? Thanks!

Comment: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stay consistent with your first code snippet, you would need the code below

```
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

In the first piece of code you make the assignment below

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO");
```

Later on when you use `x`, you say `x[0]`

Likewise if you avoid assigning `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO");` to the variable `x`, you still must include the `[]` as you would have done if you had made the assignment to `x`

Comment: It gave me "[object Element]" as result, not the calue of <CAJA1> :(

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing in your code, it seems that in your original you accessed an element in the array that was x by x[i]

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CAJA1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Yet, in the second posting without the for loop, you don't.

```
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INFO").getElementsByTagName("CAJA1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

xmlDoc never has an element accessed i.e `document.write(xmlDoc[0].getElementsByTagName("INFO").getElementsByTagName("CAJA1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);`